# how to remove previous class and add new class in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am storing my primary key as Classname

everytime this function called i will have new primary key key,

```
 function OnBtnShowPopupClick(elementID) {
                ASPxClientPopupControl1.ShowAtElementByID(elementID);
                $("#hiddenTag").addClass(elementID);
            }
```

what i want is to remove previous classname and add new className

how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

i.e

```
$("#hiddenTag").removeClass('someclass').addClass(elementID);
```

And if you don't know the class name:

```
$("#hiddenTag").removeAttr('class').addClass(elementID);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var tag = $("#hiddenTag");

tag.removeClass('oldclassname');
tag.addClass('newclassname');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use removeAttr if you do not know the name of class,

```
 function OnBtnShowPopupClick(elementID) {
            ASPxClientPopupControl1.ShowAtElementByID(elementID);
            $("#hiddenTag").removeAttr('class');
            $("#hiddenTag").addClass(elementID);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use `data()` method to store the class within the element so it can be removed next time tag is updated. This is used in situations where element may have multiple classes and you only want one removed. Use of `removeAttr('class')` would take away all classes applied to the element

```
function OnBtnShowPopupClick(elementID) {
    ASPxClientPopupControl1.ShowAtElementByID(elementID);
    var $tag = $("#hiddenTag"), currClass = $tag.data('currClass');
        if (currClass) {
            $tag.removeClass(currClass);
        }

        $tag.addClass(elementID).data('currClass', elementID) ;

};
```

Comment: Isn't that a tad overkill? Just `removeAttr` to get rid of the class if you don't know the name and you don't need to store anything anywhere. Faster load times and all. Unless I have missed a point.

Comment: @webnoob  how do you know element may not have multiple classes as many widgets do? `removeAttr('class')` wipes them all out, whereas this way only removes target class

Comment: I assume you mean `removeAttr`? Agreed, this would be better suited in that case. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @webnoob yes... other solutions using `removeClass` don't show storage method for the old class either

Answer (score 0):

You can "remove" and "add" a Class all in one swoop with the following:

```
var tag = $("#hiddenTag");
tag.removeClass('oldclassname').addClass(elementID);
```